# What is the origin of the term "hit point"?

Tags: etymology

I've looked this up on several sites, including [Wiktionary.com](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hit_point), [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/hit%20point?fromAsk=true&o=100074), and [etymonline.com](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=hit+point&searchmode=none), but the results in all three are the same: no results.

I was just wondering, where did this term come from? Who coined it? When did it come into use? Does anyone have information regarding this word?

Edit: The only context would be in gaming, where the hitpoints of a character are shown.

Comment: Can you give us a context?

Comment: The link you provided for Wiktionary.com did have an entry: http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hit_point  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Health_(gaming)#History

Comment: But does it tell about its origin?

Comment: If there's no good site about it, maybe the folks at Gamers.SE would know of some history.

Comment: On that, I do seem to remember some discussion on gamers regarding the origin of hit points as a game mechanic.

Comment: Could you please provide a link @Joe, I can't seem to find it. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, seems like I misremembered. I believe this is probably what I was thinking about, which is about XP rather than HP... http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/7473/who-created-the-idea-of-experience-points

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hit Points as a way of referencing the general remaining health of a person is taken from the game [Dungeons and Dragons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dungeons_&_Dragons), originally published back in the '70s. It was the first really popular stat-based role-playing game, and became kind of a touchstone for geekyness.

The idea was that you had a given number of hit points, based on your character class, constitution, and level. When attacked, you lose a certain number based on the power of the attack and a die roll. When/if your "HP" drops to 0, you die.

There are other games that use a "hit point" system these days, and probably were before D&D, but that is the game that popularized the concept. If you hear someone talking about "hit points" in real life, they are making a nerdy D&D reference.

Comment: Clearly D&D was the beginning of "HP's" popularity, if not the origin of the idea, but I'm not willing to search through the rules for the plethora of wargames put out by Avalon Hill years ago for the pre D&D era geeks.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avalon_Hill

Comment: Can you please provide a definite link that clearly states that "hit point" actually was invented by D&D?

Comment: Thursagen - I can't because it wasn't. As I said in the answer, D&D didn't invent the concept, so much as *popularize* it. IMHO that is the more important activity, and thus D&D deserves the lion's share of the credit. Nobody is thinking "that wargame called Ironclads" when hearing a snarky reference to hitpoints.

Answer (score 8):

The terms *defense strength points* and *attack strength points*, which were used in old board games or war games, could have eventually been shortened to *hit points* and then used in other categories, such as role playing games like D&D.  Alternatively, the term may have been coined at the time of D&D and then began to be used for the older games for short.

From [BoardGameGeek.com](http://www.boardgamegeek.com/thread/435785/one-hit-kills-vs-hit-points):

> Naval wargames are notorious for the many-hit-points feature. One of the cool things about tactical naval games is that a ship can take (or inflict) so many different kinds of damage.

Whether the term in reference to games is old as *[Battleship](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battleship_%28game%29),* can't be determined merely from the quote above, unfortunately.

I don't know if it is significant that the [NGram](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=hit%20points,hit%20point&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) shows the use of the phrase went up shortly after D&D's invention in 1974.

Comment: You might be interested in the short history here: <http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Health_(gaming)#History>

Comment: According to [this interview](http://pc.gamespy.com/articles/540/540395p3.html) with Dave Arneson (co-creator of D&D), he used "hit points" based on a game he'd developed earlier called *Ironclads*. The addition of "hit points" and "armor class" appear to be innovations to role playing introduced by D&D (Ironclads seems to be unpublished?).

Comment: Would have voted this up, rather than make my own answer, but popular "HP" references are all references back to D&D (or more modern games modeled after it). I realize Gygax didn't invent the concept from whole cloth, but he's the parent source for everyone else.

Comment: @Kit, http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/2800/ironclads was published in 1979.  Wargames were popular in geek circles even before D&D.

Comment: @T.E.D. Gygax didn't invent the concept, Arneson did.  If you read the interview, he came up with it so that the individual battles would last longer. It was an innovation to the classic matrix-style wargames that were popular prior to that. At least, that it how it seems to me, but I may be misinterpreting it.